# Migrating from Thunderbird to Microsoft Outlook

Tags: thunderbird

Is there a way to migrate from Thunderbird running on Ubuntu back to Microsoft Outlook running on Windows 7?

Comment: [Export Thunderbird to Outlook](http://www.aid4mail.com/export-thunderbird-to-outlook.php)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without any external solution.
Few months ago, I have solved the same issue by email [conversion tool](http://www.mboxtopst.filefixutility.com/thunderbird-to-outlook-pst.html).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you want to to that :).  See if [this helps](http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/th2outlook.php)

once you do step 2 Locate mbox files in Thunderbird, copy them to the windows machine and proceed to step 3

Answer (score 0):

You may copy your Thunderbird mail folders such as: Inbox, Draft, Sent and Trash etc to your Windows machine and convert them to Outlook PST file by using a e-mail migration [tool](http://www.mailsdaddy.com/mbox-to-pst-converter/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the manual solution to migrate thunderbird to outlook. If not then try manual solution. With manual solution you can easily convert thunderbird mbox file to outlook. follow the few steps.
Open Outlook to import MBOX files to PST >> File >> Import/ Export >> Import Internet Mail and Addresses >> Click Next >> select mbox file >> Next and finish.

If you already tried manual solution & it does not work for you. Then in such case I would advice you to try thunderbird migration tool. It will definitely works for you. Please try and let me know about the result. https://www.gaintools.com/mbox/pst/